# How to check if URL contains certain words?

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7, preg-match-all, preg-grep

I want to show  custom content if current URL contain certain words.

So far, I'm able to achieve this if the URL contains just the word, 'cart', using the code below. However, I want to be able to check for other words like 'blog', 'event' and 'news'. How do I go about this.

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$find = 'cart';
$pos = strpos($path, $find);
if ($pos !== false && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'path/to/site') !== false) : 
            ?>
  Custom content      
<?php else: ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array but use `preg_grep` instead.  IMO it's the correct `preg_` function for this use case.

> [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) — Return array entries that match the pattern

```
 //www.example.com?foo[]=somewords&foo[]=shopping+cart

//for testing
$_GET['foo'] = ['somewords', 'shopping cart'];

$foo = empty($_GET['foo']) ? [] : $_GET['foo'];

$words = ['cart','foo','bar'];

$words = array_map(function($item){
             return preg_quote($item,'/');
        },$words);

$array = preg_grep('/\b('.implode('|', $words).')\b/', $foo);

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => shopping cart
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b267123a27fed86459ba42b40b184050221fbad)

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array and loop through it .. IE

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = 'cart';
$arr[1] = 'foo';
$arr[2] = 'bar';

foreach($arr as $find){

   $pos = strpos($path, $find);
   if ($pos !== false && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'path/to/site') !== false){ 
      echo "custom content";
      break; // To exit the loop if custom content is found -- Prevents it showing twice or more
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence for the edit .. I was hasty with the ole copy paste!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions such as `preg_match_all()`:

#### Code

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$find = '/(curt|blog|event|news)/i';
$number_of_words_in_my_path  = preg_match_all($find, $path);
if ($number_of_words_in_my_path > 0 && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'path/to/site') !== false) : 
            ?>
  Custom content
<?php else: ?>
```